# rendering string using $sce.trustAsHtml returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, parsing

I'm trying to parse a string to a chars array, surrounding each char with `<span></span>`. the function to commit the parse works and each char is surround with the `<span>` tag.
function to parse:

```
app.controller('tableCtrl',function($scope,$sce) {

    //parse cron_format and edit each digit individually
    $scope.parse = function (cron_format){
        var parsed = cron_format.split(" ");
        for(var i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
            parsed[i] = '<span>' + parsed[i] + '</span>';
        }
    $scope.parsedCron = $sce.trustAsHtml(parsed.toString());
    return $scope.parsedCron;
    }
});
```

what I'm getting in the `<td>` its this string:

`<span>*/3</span>,<span>*</span>,<span>*</span>,<span>*</span>,<span>*</span>`

why won't the `<span>` render?
here is the table where im trying to add the result:

```
    <tbody ng-repeat="(user_id,script_id) in data  | filter: test">
        <tr ng-repeat="(script_id, cron_format) in script_id">
            <td>{{user(user_id)}}</td>
            <td>{{script(script_id)}}</td>
            **<td>{{parse(cron_format)}}</td>**
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do here; `parsed` is an array, but you are trying to pass it to a function `$sce.trustAsHtml` that only operates on strings.

Comment: ok, so i changed the two last lines to `        $scope.parsedCron = $sce.trustAsHtml(parsed.toString());
        return $scope.parsedCron;` and the result is: `<span>*/3</span>,<span>*</span>,<span>*</span>,<span>*</span>,<span>*</span> ` in the <td> ,  again <span> wont ender

Comment: You shouldn't return `$scope.parsedCron` in your function. It'd be better if you return just a string value, and assign it to a $scope property anywhere inside the controller.

Comment: thx for advice but than where and how does the rendering takes place?

Comment: no, im trying to do the exact opposite, not showing the <span> -> render it

Comment: Instead of rendering those span pieces, you could make an array of the values and do a ng-repeat. All these html to be rendered just seems wrong.

Comment: i tried to do that but i couldn't figure out why...any direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.controller('tableCtrl',function($scope) {

  $scope.letters = function(cron_format){
    return cron_format.split('');
  }
}});
```

The template:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="(user_id,script_id) in data  | filter: test">
    <tr ng-repeat="(script_id, cron_format) in script_id">
        <td>{{user(user_id)}}</td>
        <td>{{script(script_id)}}</td>
        **<td><span ng-repeat="l in letters(cron_format)">{{l}}</span></td>**
    </tr>
</tbody>
```